# Finding strings using an index - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a character array list and wish to tally the number of substring occurrences against an index held in a numerical vector chr:

```
list =
CCNNCCCNNNCNNCN

chr =

     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
     2
```

Ordinarily, I am searching for adjacent string pairs i.e. 'NN' and utilise this method:

```
Count(:,1) = accumarray(chr(intersect([strfind(list,'CC')],find(~diff(chr)))),1);
```

Using ~diff(chr) to ensure the pattern matching does not cross index boundaries.

However, now I want to match single letter strings i.e. 'N' - how can I accomplish this? The above method means the last letter in each index is missed and not counted.

The desired result for the above example would be a two column matrix detailing the number of 'C's and 'N's within each index:

```
C     N
2     2
5     6
```

i.e. there are 2C's and 2N's within index '1' (stored in `chr`) - the count then restarts from 0 for the next '2' - where there are 5C's and 6N's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[u, ~, v] = unique(list);          %// get unique labels for list in variable v
result = full(sparse(chr, v, 1));  %// accumulate combinations of chr and v
```

This works for an arbitrary number of letters in `list`, an arbitrary number of indices in `chr`, and `chr` not necessarily sorted.

In your example

```
list = 'CCNNCCCNNNCNNCN';
chr = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2].';
```

which produces

```
result =
     2     2
     5     6
```

The letter associated with each column of `result` is given by `u`:

```
u =
CN
```

Comment: Very concise +1. What is the ~ doing within [u,~,v]?

Comment: `~` is just a way of discarding the second output of `unique`. It would be functionally equivalent to `[u, x, v] = unique(list); clear x`